# Open two programs whitout typing path

Tags: trojan

I want to make a program that opens two different programs (one virus file that infects the computer and one that is the real program). I have tried with .bat files, but it requires me to write the path to the file that includes the name of the targets user account. The problem is that i don't know what the target has named his account. Is there any way a program can search the sub folder and find the target programs automaticly? (Im planning on having that program with the folder "first" and in that folder the virus and the actual program will be)
Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 0):

You can use Veil-Framework or metasploit to embed a payload into a file, and it accepts several different formats. Then you have to use social engeenering to distribute the infected file. Youll have to do some tests in local to ensure that infected file evades antivirus (the av evasion is the hard thing to do here as signatures of known payloads are also known by av software).
Renember that infecting a remote computer not owned by you can be considered a delictive act an can get you into legal issues.

Hope this helps.